# MySQL Update a column depending on multi tables

Tags: mysql

I have a question regarding updating a MySQL database.

I have three tables: Match, Submission and SubmissionVersion. A SubmissionVersion can be set as 'Favorite'. But I can't just query `UPDATE SubmissionVersion SET IsFavorite = 1 WHERE ID = $ID` because of the relation to a Submission and than the Match. My question is how can I update a SubmissionVersion column with a MySQL Query with two joins? I've tried this query but I can't get it to work.

```
UPDATE
    SubmissionVersion
JOIN
    Submission
ON
    Submission.ID, SubmissionVersion.SubmissionID
JOIN
    Match
ON
    Match.ID ON Submission.MatchID
SET
    SubmissionVersion.IsFavorite    = ".$Index."
WHERE
    SubmissionVersion.ID        = ".$ID."
AND
    Match.ID            = ".$MatchID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE SubmissionVersion sv
SET    sv.IsFavorite = ".$Index."
WHERE  sv.ID = ".$ID."
AND    sv.ID IN (
       SELECT s.ID
       FROM   Submission s
       WHERE  s.MatchID  = ".$MatchID'")
```

If I understand your statement correctly, that should work.

I eliminated the Match table completely since you're just checking the value against a column in Submission.

Comment: Btw, there was one mistake in the query. sv.ID should have been sv.SubmissionID, figured this one out myself after seeing some strange updates in the database ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with saying that MATCH is MySQL's reserved word, so needs to be put into backticks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: I have it in backticks, but SO has backticks reserved for codetyping :) Thanks for the mention by the way.

Comment: Hah... totally forgot that :D